# A local approach to adjunctions in a 2-category

Tags: category-theory, 2-categories

I have trouble understanding the following pragraph in Stephen Lack's *A 2-Categories Companion*. You can find it near the bottom of page 8, [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702535) is a link the article.

> The local approach to adjunctions also works well here, provided that one uses generalized objects rather than objects. For any 1-cells $a:X\to A$ and $b:X\to B$,
> there is a bijection between 2-cells $fa\to b$ and 2-cells $a\to ub$. One now has
> naturality with respect to both 1-cells $x:Y\to X$, and 2-cells $a\to a'$ or $b\to b'$.
> This local-global correspondence can be proved more or less as in the usual case, or
> it can be deduced from the usual case using a suitable version of the Yoneda lemma. In fact the global-to-local part...

I am interested in the local-to-global part. What do they mean when they say that $f \dashv u$ can be deduced with help of a suitable version of the Yoneda lemma? What is the version of the Yoneda lemma I have to use?

Comment: Consider the 2-categorical Yoneda lemma, which extends the Yoneda lemma to 2-categories by incorporating 2-cells in addition to 1-cells, to deduce the local-to-global adjunction $f \dashv u$.

Comment: I know about the 2-categorical lemma, I am just failing to deduce $f\dashv u$ from it. Can you show me how it works?

Comment: To deduce the global adjunction $f \dashv u$ using the 2-Yoneda lemma, consider contravariant representable 2-functors. Apply them to local adjunctions, yielding another adjunction in Cat. Use the 2-Yoneda lemma's bijection to construct unit and counit transformations, ensuring triangle equations hold, thus establishing $f \dashv u$.

Comment: @Lexponent I do not understand what you mean :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lexponent has given a proof that spells out the details, but perhaps it would also be useful to give a higher level perspective of what's going on.

The claim Lack is essentially making is this: given 1-cells $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to A$ in a 2-category $\mathcal K$, the following are equivalent.

1. $f \dashv g$ in $\mathcal K$.
2. For all objects $X \in \mathcal K$, we have $\mathcal K[X, f] \dashv \mathcal K[X, g]$ in $\mathbf{Cat}$ 2-natural in $X$.

If you spell out (3), you recover Lack's description of the "local approach" to adjunctions in a 2-category: for each object $X$ and 1-cells $a : X \to A$ and $b : X \to B$, there is a bijection between 2-cells $f a \Rightarrow b$ and 2-cells $a \Rightarrow g b$. 2-naturality comes for free, since the bijections are induced by whiskering with the unit, which arises from taking $X = A$, $a = 1_A$, $b = f$; and the counit, which arises from taking $X = B$, $a = g$, $b = 1_B$.

The key observation in establishing the equivalence of these two definitions is that (2) is an adjunction in the 2-presheaf category $[\mathcal K^\circ, \mathbf{Cat}]$. The equivalence between then follows from the 2-Yoneda lemma.

(1) ⇒ (2). The 2-Yoneda embedding $\mathcal K[X, {-}]$ of $X$ is a 2-functor, and 2-functors preserve adjunctions.

(2) ⇒ (1). The 2-Yoneda lemma implies that the 2-Yoneda embedding $\mathcal K[X, {-}]$ of $X$ is locally fully faithful, and hence reflects adjunctions. Conceptually, this is because adjunctions $f \dashv g$ are defined in terms of 2-cells (the unit and the counit) and equations between them, which are respected by locally fully faithfulness (just as fully faithful functors preserve all diagrammatic definitions).

Comment: very heplful, thx! one question, you write "the 2 yoneda embedding $K(X,-)$", but I thought the 2-Yoneda embedding is of the form $K\to 2Cat(K^{op},Cat)$. also, is the 2Yoneda embedding not even locally an equivalence?

Comment: ahhh, i see. y being locally fully faithful makes it so that y reflects the property of a pair of being adjoint to each other, because one can lift the 2cells. y being  locally an equivalence means that it even reflects the property of having an adjoint, because i can lift 1 cells too.

Comment: ahhhhh, an adjunction in $2Cat(K^{op},Cat)$ consists of a bunch of adjunctions in $Cat$, one for each 0cell $X$ :)

Comment: Thanks!!  you helped me a lot

Comment: Ah yes, when I wrote "the 2-Yoneda embedding $\mathcal K[X, {-}]$", I really meant "the 2-Yoneda embedding *of $X$*" (i.e. the evaluation of the Yoneda embedding at $X$). I'll clarify that.

Comment: Your comments regarding fully faithfulness are correct, yes :)

Answer (score 4):

Let me provide a step-by-step explanation of how to deduce the adjunction $f \dashv u$ using the 2-categorical Yoneda lemma.

1. Start with the given adjunction $f \dashv u$ in the 2-category $\mathscr{K}$.
2. Consider the representable 2-functor $\mathscr{K}(X, -) : \mathscr{K} \rightarrow \mathrm{Cat}$, where $X$ is any object in $\mathscr{K}$.
3. Apply the 2-categorical Yoneda lemma to the representable 2-functor $\mathscr{K}(X, -)$. This tells us that, for any 1-cell $a : X \rightarrow A$ and any 1-cell $b : X \rightarrow B$, there is a bijection between 2-cells $f a \rightarrow b$ and 2-cells $a \rightarrow u b$, natural in both $a$ and $b$.
4. Now, we want to deduce the adjunction $f \dashv u$ from this bijection. To do this, consider the 1-cells $a : X \rightarrow A$ and $b : X \rightarrow B$ as fixed.
5. By the naturality in both $a$ and $b$, we can find two natural transformations, $\alpha: \mathscr{K}(X, f a) \rightarrow \mathscr{K}(X, b)$ and $\beta: \mathscr{K}(X, a) \rightarrow \mathscr{K}(X, u b)$, such that the bijection between 2-cells $f a \rightarrow b$ and 2-cells $a \rightarrow u b$ corresponds to the bijection between components of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
6. In other words, for any $x : Y \rightarrow X$, the component of $\alpha$ at $x$, denoted as $\alpha_x$, is a morphism from $f(ax) \rightarrow bx$ in $\mathscr{K}(Y, B)$, and the component of $\beta$ at $x$, denoted as $\beta_x$, is a morphism from $ax \rightarrow u(bx)$ in $\mathscr{K}(Y, A)$.
7. Since these natural transformations are given by the 2-categorical Yoneda lemma, we can conclude that $f \dashv u$ holds in the 2-category $\mathscr{K}$, as the bijection between 2-cells $f a \rightarrow b$ and 2-cells $a \rightarrow u b$ given by the Yoneda lemma is exactly what we need for a local description of the adjunction.

Hence, the 2-categorical Yoneda lemma provides a bijection between 2-cells $f a \rightarrow b$ and 2-cells $a \rightarrow u b$, which is natural in both $a$ and $b$. This bijection allows us to deduce the adjunction $f \dashv u$ by relating the components of the natural transformations given by the Yoneda lemma to the morphisms in the 2-category $\mathscr{K}$.